# Using multiple variable with same name in dynamic SOQL

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql, loop, variable-names

Good day everyone I have some problem in regards with using dynamic query with too many variables. To explain further below is some part of my code.

```
String QueryString = '';
List<List<String>> whereInList = new List<List<String>>();
WhereInList.add(new List<String>{'FirstName','0'});
WhereInList.add(new List<String>{'LastName','1'});
WhereInList.add(new List<String>{'Email','2'});

Map<String, Set<Object>> mapWhereField = new Map<String, Set<Object>>();
mapWhereField.put('FirstName',new Set<Object>{'Anna','Mary','John'});
mapWhereField.put('LastName',new Set<Object>{'Doe','Kendrick','Jane'});
mapWhereField.put('Email',new Set<Object>{'test@test.com','sample@sample.com','anna@gmail.com'});

QueryString += 'Select Id,FirstName,LastName,Email FROM Contact WHERE ';
for(List<String> whereObject : whereInList) {

  Set<Object> whereData = mapWhereField.get(whereObject[0]);

  Set<String> tempWhereList = new Set<String>();    
  for(Object parsedField: whereData){
    tempWhereList.add((String) parsedField);
  } 

  //System.debug('tempWhereList : ' + tempWhereList + ' size : ' + tempWhereList.size());
  QueryString += whereObject[0] + ' IN :tempWhereList AND ';


}

System.debug('The WHERE QUERY' + QueryString.substring(0, QueryString.length()-4));
return Database.query(QueryString.substring(0, QueryString.length()-4));
```

Based on the sample code above the System debug looks like this:

```
Select Id,FirstName,LastName,Email FROM Contact WHERE FirstName IN :tempWhereList AND LastName IN :tempWhereList AND Email IN :tempWhereList
```

When I try to run my code it return no result(0 column).The thing that i'm confuse is that I am expecting to get some result because some of this data is already in salesforce. I've tried to query it in workbench and I've seen the records. This is how I put it in the workbench.

```
Select Id,FirstName,LastName,Email FROM Contact WHERE FirstName IN ('Anna', 'Mary', 'John') AND LastName IN ('Doe','Kendrick','Jane') AND Email IN ('test@test.com','sample@sample.com','anna@gmail.com')
```

My question is this, does my variable data is overriden because it has only one name ? What is the best solution to fix this using a similar concept of what I did? Please Help. Thank you

Comment: N.B. your third mapWhere uses the wrong key - should be `'Email'`

Comment: @crop1645 I am sorry for that typo error. I will update my question.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'll be buggered.

Apparently the variable that is declared within the `for` loop is still available outside the `for` loop.  It works with `if` statements as well as general scope declarations.

I've created another question for those interested in following the issue of the scope of the variables:  [Variable scope - database.query() has access to variables not in scope](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/113091/variable-scope-database-query-has-access-to-variables-not-in-scope)

Going back to your question, I'd assume the value of `tempWhereList` is only calculated once; when the query is executed.

If constructing your query this way, I'd probably split it out into the various exact strings (assuming you're not working with huge amounts of data).

i.e. `IN ('Anna', 'Mary', 'John')` rather than `IN :variable`

You can achieve this by replacing:

`QueryString += whereObject[0] + ' IN :tempWhereList AND ';`

with:

`QueryString += whereObject[0] + ' IN (\'' + String.join(new List<String>{tempWhereList}, '\',\'') + '\') AND';`

Although I'd probably re-work the script a bit.

Comment: @Nick Cook I am not sure if this is really what happen here. Because when I only have one value for my "whereInList" variable I will a get a correct data from my query.

Comment: @NickCook The question was edited-- it wasn't like that before.

Comment: @sfdcfox I am really trying to figure out I am missing but when I try to put only one value "whereInList" variable. Like for example I will only add Email, the code will work . It will give a result.

Comment: @NickCook Can you please explain what do you mean by your first suggestion ? Can you please give me what I am missing in my current code ?

Comment: @Hope It shouldn't.  Do the results actually match the criteria?

Comment: @NickCook Do you mean the results when I only have add One value in my "whereInList" variable ? Yes the result match the criteria. I also do the first suggestion you've given. The result is the same.