# Variable scope - database.query() has access to variables not in scope

Tags: apex, query, variable-scope

I was answering a question and this little inconsistency popped up.  Just wondering if anyone has come across it before, or if anyone knows why this happens.

A variable that is declared within some form of scoped element (`if`, `for` loop, etc.) shouldn't be available outside that scope.

i.e.

```
{
    // accountNames variable is not available outside this scope
    Set<String> accountNames = new Set<String> {'Test Account'};
}

system.debug(accountNames);
```

This debug statement fails with the message:

> Variable does not exist: accountNames

However, if this is part of a query string being generated, the `Database.query()` call somehow has access to it.

```
String queryString = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM Account';

if(true)
{
    // accountNames variable is not available outside the `if` statement
    Set<String> accountNames = new Set<String> {'Test Account'};
    queryString += ' WHERE Name IN :accountNames';
}

// this debug will fail if you uncomment it
// system.debug(accountNames);

// however the query somehow has access to it.
// create an account called Test Account to prove it.

system.debug('queryString: ' + queryString);
system.debug('queryString result: ' + database.query(queryString));
```

But, Salesforce is smart enough to know that it's not just some random string, so the following will fail:

```
// Alternatively, use a random string as the variable name, and salesforce 
// is smart enough to know it's gibberish
String queryString2 = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM Account';

if(true)
{
    queryString2 += ' WHERE Name IN :randomString';
}

try
{
    system.debug('queryString2 result: ' + database.query(queryString2));
    system.assert(false);
}
catch (QueryException qe) 
{
    system.debug(':randomString is gibberish: ' + qe.getMessage());
}
```

---

**Edit:**

Interestingly, the `:randomString` is definitely calculated only when the query is executed.

```
String queryString3 = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM Account';
String queryString4 = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM Account';

if(true)
{
    // assign to query 3 before it has a value
    queryString3 += ' WHERE Name IN :randomString';

    // assign to query 4 after it has been declared
    Set<String> randomString = new Set<String>{'Test Account'};
    queryString4 += ' WHERE Name IN :randomString';
}

// both queries return correct results, regardless of when the variable was declared
system.debug('queryString3 result: ' + database.query(queryString3));
system.debug('queryString4 result: ' + database.query(queryString4));
```

But it's not an open slather.  The following throws an error:

```
String queryString = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name = :someField';
someMethod();
system.debug('queryString result: ' + database.query(queryString));

void someMethod()
{
    String someField = 'Test Account';
    system.debug('someField: ' + someField);
}
```

---

Does anyone know why this is the case, or have an explanation why this would work?

As far as I can tell, at the time that the `accountNames` variable is in scope, no part of the code knows that it's anything other than a string.

Comment: Are you sure there's nowhere else in context that you are defining this variable name? I can reproduce in Execute Anonymous so this is just...weird.

Comment: You've passed `accountNames` by reference using another variable when you added it to `queryString` using the `+=`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson All I'm using is the posted code in Execute Anonymous.

Comment: @crmprogdev Not sure I understand. Isn't `:accountNames` just a string at that point in the code? Or is Salesforce behind the scenes already doing some magic with it at that point?  Is there a way to test this?

Comment: Yes, it's just a string. That's all a query string is, is "just a string" until Salesforce creates the dynamic query during run time. It's a bit like casting.

Comment: Definitely a bug. I guess we're going to have to report this.

Comment: Calling a method changes to a new transaction context, clearing the heap.

Comment: Take a look at [my conjecture in this later Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/332999/50252). I don't think this is a bug or related to garbage collection, but rather a side-effect of the "compiler" and how it handles dynamic SOQL bindings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Conjecture**

This seems like an issue with the garbage collector internals, as if exiting the block scope created by `if`/`do`/`for`, etc does not cause the garbage collector to run and clear out heap variables that are no longer visible. You'll have to open a case to find anything more definite.

**Evidence (?)**

I ran the following and consider it of interest:

```
system.debug(Limits.getHeapSize()); // 1047
if (true)
{
    List<Integer> values = new List<Integer>();
    for (Integer i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) values.add(i);
}
system.debug(Limits.getHeapSize()); // 12001063
```

The following results in a negligible reduction in heap size (13 bytes), probably because `i` gets collected:

```
// external class 
public static List<Integer> getValues()
{
    List<Integer> values = new List<Integer>();
    for (Integer i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) values.add(i);
    return values;
}
// execute anonymous

system.debug(Limits.getHeapSize()); // 1045
if (true)
{
    List<Integer> values = MyClass.getValues();
}
system.debug(Limits.getHeapSize()); // 12001050
```

The following seems to indicate `METHOD_EXIT` calls the garbage collector:

```
system.debug(Limits.getHeapSize()); // 1045
if (true)
{
    Throwaway.getValues();
}
system.debug(Limits.getHeapSize()); // 1046
```

**Experimentation**

I tried to see if it is a timing issue with the following:

```
String queryString = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM Account';
if(true)
{
    Set<String> accountNames = new Set<String> {'Test'};
    queryString += ' WHERE Name IN :accountNames';
}
for (Integer i=0; i<1000000; i++) String.isBlank('abc123');
system.debug('queryString result: ' + database.query(queryString));
```

Still works.

It doesn't seem related to how you're switching context either.

```
do
{
    Set<String> accountNames = new Set<String> {'Test'};
    queryString += ' WHERE Name IN :accountNames';
}
while (false);
```

Still works.

**Context Switching**

Passing the query string to a `@future` will fail. The following `Batchable` will find the right batches, but fail on the `execute` block. It will also fail on the `finish` block if you comment the `execute` body.

```
public class Throwaway implements Database.Batchable<SObject>
{
    String query;
    public Throwaway()
    {
        query = 'SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = :hiddenValue';
        if (true) { String hiddenValue = 'Test'; }
    }
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc)
    {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<SObject> records)
    {
        system.debug(Database.query(query));
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc)
    {
        system.debug(Database.query(query));
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I ran your heapSize test but placed the `for` loop in a separate method, and the heapSize at the end doesn't grow. I'd say that's more expected, which points more to your theory on the garbage collector.

Comment: Which part of the for loop? That's still somewhat of a context switch. All very curious, great question!

Comment: I put everything between the two debug(heapSize) statements in a separate method.

Comment: Seems like `METHOD_EXIT` may call the garbage collector then. @NickCook

Comment: References declared within a method will be on the stack with the stack normally popped at the exit of the method not the exit of a block; the block scoping rules are a language design decision. Garbage collection of the heap is a separate (and infrequent) event.

Comment: Just a side note. The issue here seems to be about dynamic SOQL not correctly identifying the appropriate scope - Garbage collection is a different concept. It's not uncommon for objects that are out of scope to wait for a GC sweep, as there isn't much point wasting CPU time doing a sweep when there is still free memory.

Comment: I ran into this issue today ... Thanks for all the explanations above!

Comment: I just ran into this, I couldn't believe how this code wasn't failing in our tests. This looks like a dangerous bug (?) to have been around for so long, the day they decide to change/fix it so many things are going to break. Thank you for all the investigation Adrian