# SOQL bind variable scope behavior

Tags: soql, dynamic-soql, variable-scope

After I posted this question, I found a similar post that seemed to answer it: [Variable scope - database.query() has access to variables not in scope](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/113091/42931). I'll leave this in place for now, as I am not sure how to mark my own question as a duplicate

In attempting to debug a SOQL query error, I encountered a strange behavior with Database.query and bind variables. Specifically, when I run this code:

```
String userQuery = 'SELECT Id FROM User';
if (true) {
    List<String> firstNames = new List<String>{'James','Joe'};
    userQuery += ' WHERE FirstName IN :firstNames';
}
Database.query(userQuery);
```

the Database.query statement executes with no errors, despite the fact that the variable firstNames does not exist in its context. However, when I add an else clause:

```
String userQuery = 'SELECT Id FROM User';
if (true) {
    List<String> firstNames = new List<String>{'James','Joe'};
    userQuery += ' WHERE FirstName IN :firstNames';
} else {
    List<String> firstNames;
}
Database.query(userQuery);
```

I receive a null object reference exception. It seems like Salesforce is checking to see if the variable is only declared once beforehand and, if so, uses its value *in the context it was declared*. This seems strange to me, so I was wondering if anybody here has any insight into what is going on under the hood.

Comment: Why did you delete this question? Seems like a good one!

Comment: @AdrianLarson I found another question very soon after I posted this one that seemed to answer what I was asking: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/113091/variable-scope-database-query-has-access-to-variables-not-in-scope?rq=1. I'm not sure if there is a way for me to indicate that this question is a duplicate myself.

Comment: This question still sheds some new light (or doubt?) on the mechanics of that scope. I find it distinct, though we'll see what other members of the community decide.

Comment: It is even more odd that it sees the variable inside the else as anything outside the else does not have access to that variable

Answer (score 4):

I have confirmed that this is a bug that has been logged at Salesforce, and will presumably be fixed at some point. You should not rely on this behavior, as it may break in a future version. Always make sure your variables are in scope.